# Simulate slower machines

Tags: performance, load-testing

Is there a utility to simulate a slower machine? I am looking for something that analyses your computer's performance, and allows you to define what kind of performance you want to simulate, and then it calculates the difference and puts some load on your system that causes the difference to occur in order to fully simulate a slower machine.

Comment: Define "load" -- memory load? IO load? CPU load? Less cores? Network saturation? The best way to simulate performance is to actually have a slower computer. Check eBay, it's not that expensive.

Comment: @Chris: Mostly CPU and memory.

Comment: Unfortunately due to hardware architectural changes, simply throwing more instructions at a CPU isn't going to make it act like an older CPU. Today's CPUs have new instructions, more efficient pipelines, power saving techniques, more cores, and faster buses. This doesn't just "speed up" the computation process, it fundamentally changes it. You're comparing apples and oranges, I'm afraid. Just go get a cheap PC.

Comment: Having said that, the easy thing to do if you just want to slow things down is to under-clock your CPU and memory. However that can be somewhat dangerous if you don't know what you're doing. And like I said, a 1 ghz Intel Core 7 won't act at all like a 1 ghz AMD Athlon.

Comment: @Chris: I don't think anyone has said 1 GHz Core i7 matches some old Celeron at 1 GHz. The point is to at least be able to somewhat make your PC slower to simulate a slower PC.

Comment: Fair enough, just "slowing it down" isn't too hard. My point was that performance is a relative term, and there's really no way to obtain some kind of performance "delta".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest setting up a virtual machine using [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/), [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), or something similar. This will allow you to modify RAM size, number of CPU cores, and other details about the machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want CPU load, why not just have a program that will take up a variable amount of load, which you vary with a slider and suck it and see.

You could have a program which alternately executes an empty for loop 'n' times and sleeps for 'm' milliseconds or microseconds, whichever you can achieve on your system.